# Undefined method `%' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting an undefined method error for '%' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Here's the simple function I have:

```
def oddball_sum(numbers)
  i =0
  arr = []

  while i <= numbers.length
     if numbers[i] % 2 != 0
     arr << numbers[i]
     end
     i +=1
  end
   return arr.sum
end
```

Can't determine the issue; the method is supposed to take an array of integers and return the sum of all the odd elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that numbers is [1,2,3,4], when i increase to 4, numbers[4] will return nil

The condition should be `i < numbers.length`

Instead of using `while`, you can also use `inject`

`numbers.inject(0) { |sum, i| i % 2 != 0 ? sum + i : sum }`

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue: Separately, when I test 'print oddball_sum([1,2,3,4])' my output is 0, instead of 4. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [arrays on the ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html) ruby is one of the elegantly written languages. less code to achieve the same result. As follow the solution this would do

`numbers.select {|num| num.odd? }.sum`